# difference between proc corr and proc corr nomiss

Tags: sas

I have a code:

```
data have;
input q1 q3 q4 q2 q6 $ bu $ q5;
cards;
1 2 3 5 sa an 3
2 . 3 . sm sa .
. 5 . 8 . na 3
1 6 3 5 su mi 2 
4 5 8 . . . 3
;
run;

proc corr data= have;
run;

proc corr data=have nomiss;
run;
```

the output of the proc corr is :

```
              q1    q3         q4        q2    q5
q1  
         1.00000    0.27735    0.94281   .     0.50000
         4          0.8211     0.0572    .     0.6667
                    3          4         2     3

and so on for q3, q4, q2 and q5.
```

the output of proc corr is :

```
            q1  q3  q4  q2  q5
q1          .   .   .   .   .
            .   .   .   .   .

q3     
            .   1.0 .   .  -1.0
            .   .   .   .   .


q4          .   .   .   .   .
            .   .   .   .   .

q2  
            .   .   .   .   .
            .   .   .   .   .

q5  
            .   -1.0 .   .  1.0
            .   .   .   .   .
```

proc corr deletes missing values pair wise. and proc corr nomiss deletes list wise. 
what does pair wise and list wise mean? how is the computing being done?

Answer (score 0):

Review the [Proc CORR documentation](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/procstat/66703/HTML/default/viewer.htm#procstat_corr_syntax01.htm) (my bold):

> [NOMISS](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/procstat/66703/HTML/default/procstat_corr_syntax01.htm#procstat.corr.nomissopt)          Excludes **observations** with missing analysis values from the analysis

Now look at the values of the numeric (i.e. analysis) variables:

```
proc print data=have;
  var _numeric_;
run;
```

Which rows (**observations**) have no missing values ? The first row and the fourth row

[image]

The computational basis of the output is also documented in section [Details: CORR Procedure](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/procstat/66703/HTML/default/viewer.htm#procstat_corr_details.htm) and has links to various methods:

> Subsections:
>   Pearson Product-Moment Correlation
>   Spearman Rank-Order Correlation
>   Kendall’s Tau-b Correlation Coefficient
>   Hoeffding Dependence Coefficient
>   Partial Correlation
>   Fisher’s z Transformation
>   Polychoric Correlation
>   Polyserial Correlation
>   Cronbach’s Coefficient Alpha
>   Confidence and Prediction Ellipses
>   ...

Comment: thanks for the documentation. I still am unclear about the output of proc corr nomiss :(

Comment: I'm not sure on the specific calculation, but two values for `q1` (1&1), `q4` (3&3), and `q2` (5&5) each have standard deviation of `0` and causes those rows and columns in output to be all missing values.